# My wordpress plugin wont be added to the left-side menu

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have built a very simple plugin and uploaded it on my wordpress account which is run on localhost. Once I activate it, its output will be shown on every page, and it wont be added to the left hand side menu of wordpress. what should I add to it to be added to the menu? I suppose it should be done using add_action but do not know how !!

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: myphotos Plugin
Description: A simple wordpress plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: Saeed Pirdost
Copyright: 2012,  Saeed Pirdost
*/
?>
<?php 
add_filter('admin_notices','myprint');
?>
function myprint()
{
    echo "hello";
}
?>
```

I used the following code as well but when I activate the plugin just a white page will be shown.

```
add_menu_page(__('My Menu Page'), __('My Menu'), 'edit_themes', 'my_new_menu', 'myprint', '', 7);
```

Comment: It's a little hard to say without seeing the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **stop opening and closing** PHP tags at every line, *you don't need that*. This is used when some HTML is happening in the middle of your PHP.

Also, the last closing `?>` of a PHP file **can/should be omitted**. It may even break a site if there is a white-space after it...

Refer to [WordPress_Coding_Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards).

---

Second, you need to decide if you want to use the function `my_print` as callback of `admin_notices` **or** of `add_menu_page`. Can it be both? In this case, yes, but really, do it only if you know what you are doing.

---

Your plugin is breaking because `add_menu_page` cannot be called directly.
**Always** check the documentation of each function that don't work as expected:
[Function_Reference/add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

---

Here's a working version of your plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: myphotos Plugin
Description: A simple wordpress plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: Saeed Pirdost
Copyright: 2012,  Saeed Pirdost
*/

add_filter( 'admin_notices', 'print_my_notice' );

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page' );

function print_my_notice()
{
    echo '<div class="updated">
           <p>I am a big notice that appears everywhere</p>
        </div>';
}

function register_custom_menu_page() 
{
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'My Menu Page', 'my-plugin-text-domain' ), 
        __( 'My Menu', 'my-plugin-text-domain' ), 
        'edit_themes', 
        'my_new_menu', 
        'print_my_menu', 
        'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Wink%2816px%29.svg', 
        7
    );      
}

function print_my_menu()
{
    echo '<div id="icon-post" class="icon32"></div>
        <h2>My plugin</h2>
            <p><a class="button-secondary" href="#"> ' 
            . __( 'I am a translation', 'my-plugin-text-domain' ) 
            . '</a>
            </p>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Open your wordpress Admin Area

```
Click on appearance->widgets

Drag and drop the Menu to desired place
```

Or

```
Click Appearance -> Menu

and click on sidebar menu
```

and add items there

Hope it helps